# Brownian motion simulation does not properly simulate particle collisions

Tags: javascript, physics, collision

I am trying to create a simulation for experimenting with the Brownian motion. The idea is to make numerous particles (points) each moving randomly and colliding with each other, while conserving the total energy. That, I did succeed programming.

Now the problematic part is to make these point-like particles collide with a big circle and program the collision correctly. The difference is I made the particles move towards a totally random angle after their collision with each other, but when they collide with the circle, their previous path and speed, together with the circle's path and speed determines the result. So what I tried to do is to convert to a coordinate system attached to the center of the circle, calculate the collision point of every particle, which entered into the circle in the previous step, then calculate the angle in which they arrived. Now then the momentum of the particle is decomposed into two components: the tangential component remains the same, while the radial component changes according to the laws of collisions. This affects the motion of the circle as well. After calculating all the collisions, we move back to the original reference system, and draw all the objects.

The code can be found below, and it seems to be broken. I guess I was mistaken when calculating with the angles, because some particles can be shown arriving to the circle at one point, then "exiting" through the other side of it. I just lost track in following it all. I'm a complete newbie to programming, so be... um... gentle, please. :) Another strange thing is that the circle trends to move to a direction it started to move early, which is not what it supposed to do.

The mass of the particles are given, the mass of the circle is calculated with it's radius.

You can find the simulation on this website:

http://sixy.uw.hu/brown

It is not finished yet, but the start button works fine. :)

The part of the code I'm asking about is here: (shall I give you the whole code?)

```
function animateParticles() {
        if ($('N').value != particleCount || $('S').value != circle.R) {
           reset();
        }

        switch (activeGraph) {
                case '#graph':
                    chartOptions.title.text = 'Távolság';
                    chartOptions.axisY.title = 'd [px]';
                    break;

        if (Date.now() > lastAnim + 22) {
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            // Particles step and collide
            for (var i in particle) {
                // Particle steps
                {
                    particle[i].x += particle[i].vx;
                    particle[i].y += particle[i].vy;
                }

                // If not in the circle
                if ((circle.x - particle[i].x) * (circle.x - particle[i].x) + (circle.y - particle[i].y) * (circle.y - particle[i].y) > circle.R * circle.R) {
                    // Collides with some of the rest of the particles
                    for (var j = 1; j <= $('N').value; j += Math.ceil(particleCount / (Math.random() * 50 + 50))) {
                        // If that's not in the circle as well
                        if ((circle.x - particle[j].x) * (circle.x - particle[j].x) + (circle.y - particle[j].y) * (circle.y - particle[j].y) > circle.R * circle.R) {
                            // If not himself
                            if (j != i) {
                                if (particle[i].coll == 0) {
                                    // Collide
                                    if (Math.pow((particle[i].x - particle[j].x), 2) + Math.pow((particle[i].y - particle[j].y), 2) <= 4) {
                                        var tkpx = (particle[i].vx + particle[j].vx) / 2;
                                        var tkpy = (particle[i].vy + particle[j].vy) / 2;
                                        var fi = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
                                        var index;
                                        var ix = particle[i].vx;
                                        var iy = particle[i].vy;

                                        particle[i].vx = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((ix - tkpx), 2) + Math.pow((iy - tkpy), 2)) * Math.cos(fi) + tkpx;
                                        particle[i].vy = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((ix - tkpx), 2) + Math.pow((iy - tkpy), 2)) * Math.sin(fi) + tkpy;
                                        particle[j].vx = -Math.sqrt(Math.pow((ix - tkpx), 2) + Math.pow((iy - tkpy), 2)) * Math.cos(fi) + tkpx;
                                        particle[j].vy = -Math.sqrt(Math.pow((ix - tkpx), 2) + Math.pow((iy - tkpy), 2)) * Math.sin(fi) + tkpy;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if (particle[i].coll >= 1) {
                                particle[i].coll -= 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Collision with the walls
                {
                    if (particle[i].x >= canvas.width) {
                        var temp;
                        temp = particle[i].x - canvas.width;
                        particle[i].x = canvas.width - temp;
                        particle[i].vx *= -1

                    }
                    if (particle[i].x <= 0) {
                        var temp;
                        temp = -particle[i].x;
                        particle[i].x = temp;
                        particle[i].vx *= -1;
                    }
                    if (particle[i].y >= canvas.height) {
                        var temp;
                        temp = particle[i].y - canvas.height;
                        particle[i].y = canvas.height - temp;
                        particle[i].vy *= -1;
                    }
                    if (particle[i].y <= 0) {
                        var temp;
                        temp = -particle[i].y;
                        particle[i].y = temp;
                        particle[i].vy *= -1;
                    }
                }
            }
            //console.log(circle);
            // Circle steps and collides with particles
            var cu = 0;
            var cv = 0;
            for (var i in particle) {
                if ((circle.x - particle[i].x) * (circle.x - particle[i].x) + (circle.y - particle[i].y) * (circle.y - particle[i].y) < circle.R * circle.R) {
                    var pu;
                    var pv;
                    var px;
                    var py;
                    var px0;
                    var py0;
                    var t;
                    var t2;
                    var Tx;
                    var Ty;
                    var fi;
                    var p;
                    var q;
                    var cuu;
                    var cvv;
                    px = particle[i].x - circle.x;
                    py = particle[i].y - circle.y;
                    pu = particle[i].vx - circle.vx;
                    pv = particle[i].vy - circle.vy;
                    px0 = px - particle[i].vx;
                    py0 = py - particle[i].vy;
                    // Calculating the meeting point of the collision
                    t = (-(px0 * pu + py0 * pv) - Math.sqrt(circle.R * circle.R * (pu * pu + pv * pv) - Math.pow(px0 * pv - py0 * pu, 2))) / (pu * pu + pv * pv);
                    t2 = ((px - px0) * (px - px0) + (py - py0) * (py - py0)) / Math.sqrt(pu * pu + pv * pv) - t;
                    Tx = px0 + t * pu;
                    Ty = py0 + t * pv;
                    //console.log("TX: ", Tx);
                    //console.log("TY: ", Ty);
                    // Calculating the angle
                    {
                        if (Tx > 0 && Ty >= 0) {
                            fi = 2 * Math.PI - Math.atan(Ty / Tx);
                        }
                        else if (Tx < 0 && Ty >= 0) {
                            fi = Math.PI - Math.atan(Ty / Tx);
                        }
                        else if (Tx < 0 && Ty < 0) {
                            fi = Math.PI / 2 + Math.atan(Ty / Tx);
                        }
                        else if (Tx > 0 && Ty < 0) {
                            fi = -Math.atan(Ty / Tx);
                        }
                        else if (Tx = 0 && Ty >= 0) {
                            fi = 3 / 2 * Math.PI;
                        }
                        else if (Tx = 0 && Ty < 0) {
                            fi = Math.PI / 2;
                        }
                    }
                    //console.log("FI:", fi);
                    p = pu * Math.cos(fi) + pv * Math.sin(fi);
                    q = -pu * Math.sin(fi) + pv * Math.cos(fi);
                    cuu = 2 * q / (circle.M + 1);
                    cvv = 0;
                    q *= (1 - circle.M) / (1 + circle.M);
                    cu += cuu * Math.cos(-fi) + cvv * Math.sin(-fi);
                    cv += -cuu * Math.sin(-fi) + cvv * Math.cos(-fi);
                    //console.log("CU: ", cu);
                    //console.log("CV: ", cv);
                    pu = p * Math.cos(-fi) + q * Math.sin(-fi);
                    pv = -p * Math.sin(-fi) + q * Math.cos(-fi);
                    px = Tx + t2 * pu;
                    py = Ty + t2 * pv;
                    particle[i].x = px + circle.x;
                    particle[i].y = py + circle.y;
                    particle[i].vx = pu + circle.vx;
                    particle[i].vy = pv + circle.vy;
                }
            }
            // Moving circle
            {
                circle.vx += cu;
                circle.vy += cv;
                circle.x += circle.vx;
                circle.y += circle.vy;
                for (var i in particle) {
                    while ((circle.x - particle[i].x) * (circle.x - particle[i].x) + (circle.y - particle[i].y) * (circle.y - particle[i].y) < circle.R * circle.R) {
                        particle[i].x += circle.vx / Math.abs(circle.vx);
                        particle[i].y += circle.vy / Math.abs(circle.vy);
                    }
                }
                circlePath.push({x: circle.x, y: circle.y});
                if (Date.now() > lastDraw + 500) {
                    items.push({
                        y: Math.sqrt((circle.x - canvas.width / 2) * (circle.x - canvas.width / 2) + (circle.y - canvas.height / 2) * (circle.y - canvas.height / 2)),
                        x: (items.length + 1) / 2
                    });
                    drawChart(activeGraph);
                    lastDraw = Date.now();
                }
            }

            //console.log(circle);
            drawCircle();
            for (var i in particle) drawParticle(particle[i]);
            lastAnim = Date.now();
        }
        animation = window.requestAnimationFrame(animateParticles);
    }
```

Comment: I don't know javascript, but this seems like too much code for such a simple problem. When you write code, it is important to isolate new functionality as much as possible, before integrating it into an existing codebase. Can you give us an example case, a single particle that collides with the circle incorrectly?